# how to use the autodesk.viewing.UI.dataTable

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Can someone point me to some examples on how to use the autodesk.viewing.UI.dataTable component?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no official sample for the [DataTable](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/UI/DataTable) class yet. Here's a quick and dirty sample that should get you going:

```
class MyPanel extends Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel {
    constructor(container, id, title, options) {
        super(container, id, title, options);
        this.container.style.setProperty('z-index', '2');
        this._table = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DataTable(this);
        const rows = [
            ['Foo', 12],
            ['Bar', 34],
            ['Baz', 56]
        ];
        const cols = ['Name', 'Age'];
        this._table.setData(rows, cols);
    }
}
```

And then in your code:

```
let panel = new MyPanel(viewer.container, 'my-panel-id', 'Panel Title');
panel.setVisible(true);
```

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. We will provide a more complete example of how the class can be used, and share it with the community on the [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog).